# RXjs, chaining long poll requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, reactivex, redux-observable

I have the following `RXjs construction` (in react-observable), which chains long polling requests. The goal is to retry the request if it times out, or use the content of the `request to 1`.) update the `ui state 2`.) start a new update loop using a new `URI` from the response.

It looks like the below construction is not emitting the inner events correctly - or spamming them infinitely when using `mergeMap` instead of `exhaustMap`. What am i missing here?

```
action$.pipe(
ofType(actions.LONG_POLL_CHAIN),
exhaustMap(action =>
    from(apiClient.longPoll(uri)).pipe(flatMap(response => concat(
            of(actionLongPollingSuccess(response)),
            of(actionLongPollingContinue(response)))
        ))
)
```

in pseudo code the expected outcome should be:

```
while(true){
    action = actions.deduplicate().takeFirst();
    if(!apiClient.isLongPollingRunning())
    {
       result = apiClient.longPoll(action.uri)
       actions.push({ uri: result.uri}
       actions.push({ data: result.data}) //consumed by other service
    }
    else {
       actions.push({ uri : uri})
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make a reproducible demo on stackblitz or something similar because it's hard to understand what you want to do.

Comment: added pseudo code to better describe the use case

Comment: Does `LONG_POLL_CHAIN` action starts longpolling? Will longpolling ever end? What happens if two consecutive `LONG_POLL_CHAIN` actions are emitted?

Comment: the LONG_POLLING_CHAIN is triggered externally and should go on forever - but should limit the parallel polling actions to one at a time and kick of the next directly after the last one finishes